# Moving large files with Raspberry Pi

Tags: unix, file-io, raspberry-pi

I am trying to move files from a remote computer (OSX) to a local USB Hard Drive (320GB) connected to the Raspberry Pi (4GB).

The problem is Raspberry Pi OS is running on a 4GB card, and when I try to move the files from a drive to another, I always run out of space.

I've tried with rsync, sshfs, and a Python script to move the file in chunks, but apparently it doesn't matter, it always runs out of space ( maybe because is saving it into cache? )

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: The SSH-based solutions rsync, scp, and sftp shouldn't have that problem. I regularly move large files to a drive that isn't my boot drive when my boot drive doesn't have space. There's also netcat. Maybe your HDD is formatted as FAT32, which can't hold >4GB sized files?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use `curl` to transfer the file
[in chunks](http://jwalanta.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-wget-and-dd-to-download-file.html).

```
curl -o gpl_segment.txt -r 888-1297 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought on curl, but curl doesn't support ssh and the remote PC connection is not http. As far as I understand I would have to install a server with range header support. Thanks!